# Spring / Swagger-UI - Show example of real values in request model when user clicks on "Try it out" button

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

How do I make swagger-ui to show pre-populated real values in the Example box below?   (**The box for request model that shows when user clicks on "Try it out" button in swagger-ui**).

I am using SpringBoot/Java and I would like it to show some real values rather than data types.  It seam to do that for DOB field by default.

I have `MyModel` defined as below and I was expecting that using "`value`" in `ApiModelProperty` will set these values but it is not:

```
@ApiModel(description="blahblah")
public class MyModel {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "some notes", name = "name", required = true, value = "Bot")
    private String name;
  
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Date of birth", name = "dob", required = true)
    private OffsetDateTime dob;
  
    @ApiModelProperty(notes="How old", name = "age", required = true, value = "31")
    private Integer age;
  ...
}
```

[image]

I would like above to look like:

[image]

Comment: What are using to define this template? are you using a json/yaml? or is it defined in code?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How can I set a description and an example in Swagger with Swagger annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46584658/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `example`:

```java
@ApiModelProperty(notes = "some notes", name = "name", required = true, example = "Bot")
private String name;
```